# There is a post limit in Internet Explorer of 3926 characters. How can I bypass this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, forms, post

I've been troubleshooting this error for 12 hours now, and I think I have this narrowed down to this.

If I supply a post method, whether its a json object or a string, IE will allow anything up to ~3926 characters. Nothing else, no matter what shape or size its in. This is so long as its being passed like so :

```
<form method="post" action="/generate_csv.csv?calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=02%2F02%2F1981&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F1981&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=12.0&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=0.912328767123288&amp;calc[][total_interest]=214.14&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F1982&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F1982&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=12.0&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0&amp;calc[][total_interest]=234.72&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F1983&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F1983&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=12.0&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0&amp;calc[][total_interest]=234.72&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F1984&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F1984&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=12.0&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0027397260274&amp;calc[][total_interest]=235.36&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F1985&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F1985&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=12.0&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0&amp;calc[][total_interest]=234.72&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F1986&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F1986&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=9.5&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0&amp;calc[][total_interest]=185.82&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F1987&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F1987&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=7.5&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0&amp;calc[][total_interest]=146.7&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F1988&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F1988&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=6.0&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0027397260274&amp;calc[][total_interest]=117.68&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F1989&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F1989&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=7.0&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0&amp;calc[][total_interest]=136.92&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F1990&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F1990&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=8.0&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0&amp;calc[][total_interest]=156.48&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F1991&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F1991&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=8.5&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0&amp;calc[][total_interest]=166.26&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F1992&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F1992&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=7.5&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0027397260274&amp;calc[][total_interest]=147.1&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F1993&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F1993&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=5.5&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0&amp;calc[][total_interest]=107.58&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F1994&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F1994&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=3.5&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0&amp;calc[][total_interest]=68.46&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F1995&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F1995&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=3.5&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0&amp;calc[][total_interest]=68.46&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F1996&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F1996&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=5.5&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0027397260274&amp;calc[][total_interest]=107.87&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F1997&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F1997&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=5.5&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0&amp;calc[][total_interest]=107.58&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F1998&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F1998&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=5.5&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0&amp;calc[][total_interest]=107.58&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F1999&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F1999&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=5.5&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0&amp;calc[][total_interest]=107.58&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F2000&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F2000&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=5.0&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0027397260274&amp;calc[][total_interest]=98.07&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F2001&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F2001&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=5.5&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0&amp;calc[][total_interest]=107.58&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F2002&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F2002&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=6.0&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0&amp;calc[][total_interest]=117.36&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F2003&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F2003&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=3.0&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0&amp;calc[][total_interest]=58.68&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F2004&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F2004&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=2.0&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0027397260274&amp;calc[][total_interest]=39.23&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F2005&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F2005&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=1.0&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0&amp;calc[][total_interest]=19.56&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F2006&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F2006&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=2.0&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0&amp;calc[][total_interest]=39.12&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F2007&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F2007&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=4.0&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0&amp;calc[][total_interest]=78.24&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F2008&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F2008&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=5.5&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0027397260274&amp;calc[][total_interest]=107.87&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F2009&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F2009&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=4.0&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0&amp;calc[][total_interest]=78.24&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F2010&amp;calc[][date_paid]=12%2F31%2F2010&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=1.5&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=1.0&amp;calc[][total_interest]=29.34&amp;calc[][amount_paid]=0.0&amp;calc[][date_awarded]=1%2F1%2F2011&amp;calc[][date_paid]=02%2F09%2F2011&amp;calc[][interest_rate]=0.5&amp;calc[][principal]=1955.96&amp;calc[][tf]=0.10958904109589&amp;calc[][total_interest]=1.07" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div style="margin: 0pt; padding: 0pt; display: inline;"><input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8"><input type="hidden" value="dbxrVZT2J42AB0QdMFi2XPggVGAQKtm8IkcuIj+U2jU=" name="authenticity_token"></div>
```

In all other browsers, this passes with **no problem** at all. But IE will not tolerate this past a certain point.

Does *anyone* know how I can pass the same amount of data in a small and condensed way or even in an alternative means?

An alternative, I was thinking, could be passing an alias of the object so that the object itself is passed between controllers, but **not** through the views. This being done without ever saving the object to the database. Just thinking out loud here.

Open to any ideas. :D

My Haml:

```
= form_tag generate_csv_path(:calc => @calc.results, :total_interest => @calc.total_interest, :per_diem => @calc.per_diem, :docket_num => @calc.docket_num, :our_file_num => @calc.our_file_num) do
  = submit_tag 'Print CSV', :id => "print_csv"
```

**UPDATE**

So I'm looping through all the items trying to break them up into smaller hidden fields and they're all coming out as hashes

```
- @calc.results.each do |k, v|
  = hidden_field :calc_result, "#{k[:total_interest]}"
```

Produces:

```
"117.68"=>"",
"166.26"=>"",
"147.1"=>"",
"107.58"=>"",
"58.68"=>"",
```

So unbelievable strange.. I thought I might be able to create a value as a hash eventually. So that 1 calc_result could ahve 5 different attributes in it.

Comment: Why are you posting to a URL? Shouldn't these be hidden form fields instead?

Comment: I think IE limits URL length not post length.

Comment: @Daniel - I'm out of comfort zone because I'm not using a database to perform this. How would you have this form post with hidden_fields? I'll update above for what my haml says.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Post the data as < form > body, not as part of the URL.

URLs have length-limit. Data POSTed as form body have no limit as such, since they are part of the header (not URL)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427

UPDATE (in response to your comment)
Data as part of form body...

```
<form method="post" action="/generate_csv.csv">
 <input type="hidden" name="calc[][amount_paid]" value="0.0"/>
 ... //other fields here
</form>
```

Comment: Looking at the example above..isn't that apart of the Form Body?